# Adding to table using Jdbc & ms managment system

Tags: java, t-sql, jdbc

I bumped into this problem and i cannot figure out what is wrong with this code. I use jdbc and ms managment system for the databse and its connection.

code:

```
try {
            //create user
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users(name, pass, type) VALUES (nick=?,pass=?,type=?)",
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);            
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getNickName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword());
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, type);
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(rs.toString());
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
```

error:

```
Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are using the `?` characters is invalid in JDBC:

```
"INSERT INTO Users(name, pass, type) VALUES (nick=?,pass=?,type=?)
```

One `?` represents the whole bind variable.  Try

```
"INSERT INTO Users(name, pass, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
```

Also, use [`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) to execute an insert statement (or update, or delete).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the field names from the value list. These are already in the name list. Also use `executeUpdate` for database write operations:

```
preparedStatement = 
  conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users(name, pass, type) VALUES (?,?,?)",
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);            
preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getNickName());
preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword());
preparedStatement.setInt(3, type);
int rowCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```